# Bootstrap classes render anchor tags disfunctional

Tags: html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3, webforms

I have a rather peculiar issue and can find nothing on it on the net. I have a following anchor tag, embedded in a aspx web form. The anchor tag, calls upon another form modal-forgotpassword.aspx.

```
<a href="/controls/modal/modal-forgotpassword.aspx" data-toggle="ajaxModal" class="lost-pwd m-t-15 btn btn-default btn-block">Forgot password?</a>
```

Easy enough right?
Issue is that the link, while embedded in the web-form does not work as long as the bootstrap classes "btn btn-default btn-block" are present. Any one of the classes can be present and the tag will not work.

Tag as such:

```
<a href="/controls/modal/modal-forgotpassword.aspx" data-toggle="ajaxModal" class="lost-pwd  m-t-15">Forgot password?</a>
```

Works just fine; calls on the other webform flawlessly. I am fascinated and lost about this, did anyone ever encounter such issue with bootstrap?

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated! Please share!

P.S.: Btw, yes I can make the tag look like a button myself, its not a problem, of course, but that is not the point.

Comment: can you add the js which start the ajax call and open the modal? something similar to `$('[data-toggle="ajaxModal"]').on('click',...)`